# Can I customize In[] and Out[] headers?

Tags: notebooks, customization

Can I customize the `In[]` and `Out[]` headers?  I'd like to add `$UserName`, `$MachineName` and `DateString[]`, evaluated at cell creation time, into those headers, so it's easy to know by whom and when any particular cell was generated by a glance.  This is similar to why/how people customize UNIX terminal prompt.

Comment: [a bit old but](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938827/what-generates-the-in-out-celllabels-in-mathematica-and-how-can-i-add-automatic) ...

Comment: See `CellLabel`

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something involving `CellEpilog`:

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
 CellLabelAutoDelete -> False, 
 CellEpilog :> SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], 
                          CellLabel -> StringJoin["Kuba was here ", DateString[]]]]
```

> [image]

You can edit `Stylesheet` if you want to. I'm not sure if `out` could be modyfied this way too, but at the end of the day it is `InputCell` what is evaluated, isn't it? :)

Comment: How would you suppress all output cells this way?

Comment: @RolfMertig not sure what do you mean.